# ElasticSearch. How to pass array to the search template

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, mustache, elasticsearch-template

I have a search system in which i need to score by location. User sends his coordinates, I check whether they intersect with pre-indexed polygons. The problem is I don't know how to pass coordinates to json file. I use python library called elasticsearch.
Here is sample of how I pass search data to search template[image: Here is sample of how I pass search data to search template]

And this is how I'm trying to use it in search template file
[image]

But the problem is it gets parsed as a string, but I need an array of floats.

Answer (score 0):

For coordinates,use this format : "coordinates" : [[-77.03653, 38.897676], [-77.009051, 38.889939]]
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html

For the score please join us exemple and what you expect, but pretty sure you will have to use a https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Comment: Talking about coordinates, these coordinates are passed to json from python code using function search_template, and the only way to get it in json file is like this "{{coordinates}}", I pass a list but it gets type casted to string, when I'm accessing it in json, I can't find a way How can i get it as list

Comment: I want to increate score of restaurants, which polygons intersect with the point I pass. Client app passes me user location, and I'm making search in accordance with user coordinates and boost the ones which intersect with my point

Comment: So a sort by distance would be ok?

Comment: Actually,no. Because these polygons represent delivery areas of a restaurant, it's not so important how far they are, as if this location is in this polygon. If it is I need to boost its score

Comment: Ok can you join us 1 or 2 example? We should be able to resolve the score part. For the coordinates i cant help you, not relate to elasticsearch, you certainly have to use another json serializer or custom your formater. You should also post your code for this problem.